# Insert missing value based on other rows

Tags: r, if-statement

I have a dataframe similar (just longer). My goal is to copy the username of [2] to [8] and [5] to [7]. I know it's weird making a duplicate, but there's a reason.

I've been trying solving it with an ifelse:

```
df$Username <- ifelse(df$Name == df$Name, df$Username, NA)
```

But it doesn't work. I believe it's rather simple, but can't find a function anywhere on stackoverlow. Thanks in advance for any help.

```
# A tibble: 6 x 2
  Name           Username       
  <chr>          <chr>          
1 ZiadAboultaif  ziad_aboultaif 
2 ScottAitchison ScottAAitchison
3 DanAlbas       DanAlbas       
4 JohnAldag      jwaldag        
5 OmarAlghabra   OmarAlghabra   
6 ShafqatAli     Shafqat_Ali_1  
7 OmarAlghabra   NA
8 ScottAitchison NA

# Reproducilbe data:
df <- structure(list(Name = c("ZiadAboultaif", "ScottAitchison", "DanAlbas", 
"JohnAldag", "OmarAlghabra", "ShafqatAli"), Username = c("ziad_aboultaif", 
"ScottAAitchison", "DanAlbas", "jwaldag", "OmarAlghabra", "Shafqat_Ali_1"
)), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))
```

Comment: your reproducible data is missing the last 2 rows (7 and 8)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd use **`dplyr`**:

```
df %>% group_by(Name) %>% 
   mutate(Username=max(Username, na.rm=TRUE))
```

Output:

```
  Name           Username       
  <chr>          <chr>          
1 ZiadAboultaif  ziad_aboultaif 
2 ScottAitchison ScottAAitchison
3 DanAlbas       DanAlbas       
4 JohnAldag      jwaldag        
5 OmarAlghabra   OmarAlghabra   
6 ShafqatAli     Shafqat_Ali_1  
7 OmarAlghabra   OmarAlghabra   
8 ScottAitchison ScottAAitchison
```

To get the maximum value without having `NA`s (`na.rm=TRUE`) inside `mutate`.

Comment: smart using `max` this way!!

Comment: I've never seen max been used that way before. It'll go into my codebook... Thanks a million, it works like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution:

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- structure(list(Name = c("ZiadAboultaif", "ScottAitchison", "DanAlbas", 
"JohnAldag", "OmarAlghabra", "ShafqatAli"), Username = c("ziad_aboultaif", 
"ScottAAitchison", "DanAlbas", "jwaldag", "OmarAlghabra", "Shafqat_Ali_1"
)), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))

df <- rbind(df, c("OmarAlghabra", NA), c("ScottAitchison",NA))

df %>% 
  group_by(Name) %>% 
  fill(Username) %>% 
  ungroup

#> # A tibble: 8 × 2
#>   Name           Username       
#>   <chr>          <chr>          
#> 1 ZiadAboultaif  ziad_aboultaif 
#> 2 ScottAitchison ScottAAitchison
#> 3 DanAlbas       DanAlbas       
#> 4 JohnAldag      jwaldag        
#> 5 OmarAlghabra   OmarAlghabra   
#> 6 ShafqatAli     Shafqat_Ali_1  
#> 7 OmarAlghabra   OmarAlghabra   
#> 8 ScottAitchison ScottAAitchison
```

Comment: Thanks a lot - it works like a charm. I went with the other ^ solution although they both do the job.

Answer (score 1):

We could use `add_row` from `dplyr` package:

```
dplyr::add_row(df,df[c(5,2),], .after = 6)
```

```
  Name           Username       
  <chr>          <chr>          
1 ZiadAboultaif  ziad_aboultaif 
2 ScottAitchison ScottAAitchison
3 DanAlbas       DanAlbas       
4 JohnAldag      jwaldag        
5 OmarAlghabra   OmarAlghabra   
6 ShafqatAli     Shafqat_Ali_1  
7 OmarAlghabra   OmarAlghabra   
8 ScottAitchison ScottAAitchison
```